# How should I understand the behavior of Lazy<T> on a web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lazy-initialization

I can't tell if or when it makes sense to use `Lazy<T>` on an web server. I understand how `Lazy<T>` works and why it makes sense in the basic case where an object may not be needed on my local applications. I'm really unsure of when it *doesn't* make sense if I publish an application to a server that is used by many people. Most of what I can find about the subject isn't really related to the lifetime of objects or static members in production environments.

Questions running through my head:

1. On a static member of a class. If user 'A' triggers the initialization of the static member will another user 'B' have the benefit of not having to initialize that member?
2. What is the lifetime of a static Lazy member if it's part of something like a repository or service class that gets used in an API through dependency injection?
3. When *shouldn't* I use Lazy to initialize an object that is expensive to create?
4. For objects that are expensive to create, is there a time that it doesn't matter if I make it Lazy or not?

I could easily start making every expensive thing in my project `Lazy<T>` but that could add unnecessary overhead as well as making the code harder to read.

Comment: These are all great questions with no answer besides "check your implementation". This, in fact, has been the driving force behind adding dependency injection to every single modern web app framework, because dependency injection can defer lifetime cycle decisions to the user of the type (or implicitly to the framework for framework types).

Comment: @Blindy, when you say "check your implementation" do you mean the DI implementation or the code related to a Lazy object in general?

Comment: The latter. With DI you can explicitly state the life cycle of those objects.